# Increase row value in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to use codeigniter syntax to increase a row value.

```
        $count = 1 ;
        $this->db->where('id',$coupon->parent);
        $this->db->set('current_users', 'current_users + '.$count, FALSE);
        $this->db->update('coupons');
```

but this code increase `current_users` field amount to 2.

ex:

if `current_users` be 10 my code increase it to 12 instead of 11 !

Comment: make it like $this->db->set('current_users', "current_users + $count", FALSE);

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
    $count = 1 ;
    $this->db->where('id',$coupon->parent);
    $this->db->set('current_users', "current_users + $count", FALSE);
    $this->db->update('coupons');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try after changing this line

```
 $this->db->set('current_users', 'current_users + '.$count, FALSE);
```

To

```
 $this->db->set('current_users', "`current_users` + $count", FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 1 ;
$this->db->where('id',$coupon->parent);
$this->db->set('current_users', 'current_users+'.$count, FALSE);
$this->db->update('coupons');
```

static :

$this->db->set('current_users', 'current_users+1', FALSE);